# Is there any way to disable javadoc crashes in Android Studio with Maven plugin?

Tags: java, android, maven, plugins, gradle

I'm using **com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin** to generate a POM file and then upload it to Bintray. Though when I run `./gradlew install`, the script invokes Maven's install command, and *FAILS* on generating JavaDoc. I've already searched everywhere to find how to disable javadoc errors, but there is always one more issue I cannot solve.

Tested: 'failOnError false', disabling javadoc task (wasn't allowed), adding various parameters to `install` task for POM generation, tried different flags on the CLI, etc.

I've used [this tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. So the structure I had was...

```
// GRADLE FILE START
Standard task definitions
...
!!! JAVADOC DISABLING (basically everything I tried I put here) !!!
Importing my maven upload and bintray upload scripts (command: 'apply from') 
...
Dependencies
// GRADLE FILE END
```

What I was missing is that `androidJavadoc` and `javadoc` tasks work differently, AND that Gradle parses the file top to bottom. **It does matter where you define your stuff.**

So, I naively put the JAVADOC tasks to the middle of the file, and `:javadoc` task couldn't be overwritten, couldn't be disabled etc. - because it was only created by the `install` segment inside the `pom_install.gradle` I had imported in the next few lines.

A quick fix for most of my Gradle issues - put everything you read on StackOverflow to the end of file. It's that stupid. So the new structure...

```
// GRADLE FILE START
Standard task definitions
...
Importing my maven upload and bintray upload scripts (command: 'apply from')
...
Dependencies
...
!!! JAVADOC DISABLING (basically everything I tried I put here) !!!
// GRADLE FILE END
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show how I can disable the `:javadoc` task?

Comment: A quick search on SO? For example, I tried this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34874587/2102748

Answer (score 4):

for me running gradlew install without javadoc generation was enough to overcome this, my crash was due to a stricter javadoc format requirement added in java 8 and one of my libs was at fault

```
gradlew install -xjavadoc
```